# How to add a while(1) loop in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

In NODEJS I want a function that will keep executing after every 5 seconds, and I used while(1) loop with a time out of 5 seconds. But its not working.

```
    while(1){

            var ms=4000;
            ms += new Date().getTime();
            while (new Date() < ms){}

            execute(12345,0);

    }
```

Comment: You should use [setInterval](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_arg) instead

Comment: Or use a setTimeout if you want to execute function after 4 seconds from executing it previously

Comment: yeah i also tired that as well, but i think the problem is with while(1) loop, i think it halts all other things????

Comment: You do not have to use `while(1)`. This will initiate a never ending loop. setInterval will autmatically run your function after specific delay. If you wish to run immediately and then run after every 5 secs, try [setImmediate](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript you can create some tasks to be called on every interval needed using `setInterval`:

setInterval(functionToCallOnInterval, intervalInMilliSeconds);

```js
setInterval(function() {
  console.log('called about every 5 seconds');
}, 5000);

setInterval(myFunc, 6000);

function myFunc() {
  console.log('called about every 6 seconds');
}
```

#### Behold

`setInterval` timing is not accurate so you can't count on this for vital situations.

Answer (score 0):

You should use setInterval instead of WHILE loop.

```
setInterval(function(){
  console.log('test');
},5000);
```

This 5000 is time in ms!!

Comment: yeah i also tired that as well, but i think the problem is with while(1) loop, i think it halts all other things?????

Comment: No no, you dont need while loop ..you can just use this instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is, you are running a thread with infinite execution and thus it will freeze the browser. Instead if you will use setInterval() then a new thread will be run at regular intervals in which your function will be executed. Hope you got the concept well.